# Python: server- прочитать данные PostData из входящего запроса

Tags: python, сервер, post, сокет

Есть скрипт, самая простая реализация сервера на Python 3.7. Вопрос, как считать из входящих данных от клиента PostData?

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 80))
sock.listen(1)

try:

    while True:  # работаем постоянно
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        try:
            print('accepted connection from', addr)
            conn.recvmsg()
            data = conn.recv(1024)

            print("Data: %s" % data)
        finally:
            conn.send(b"AllOk")
            conn.close()
finally:
    sock.close()
```

Я так понял надо смотреть в сторону:
conn.recv() или conn.recvmsg() (возможно кардинально не прав)
к сожалению не могу найти нормального примера, где было бы показано, как считывать PostData....

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно что подразумевает PostData, но из контекста предполагаю что это любые данные отправленные клиентом.
Тогда это должно сработать:

```
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 8080
with socket.socket() as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('accepted connection from', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data: break
            print("Data: \n{}" .format(data.decode()))
            conn.sendall(b'allOK')
```

Если все же нужно прочитать именно тело POST запроса тогда к этому коду нужно добавить парсинг хедеров, найти там заголовок Content-Length, прочитать его значение (это длина тела запроса), дальше необходимо дойти до начала тела, от хедеров его отделяет "\r\n\r\n", и прочитать оттуда {Content-Length} байт.

Но лично я бы посоветовал использовать для этого специализированные библиотеки например Werkzeug, или что-то более высокоуровневое(Flask, Bottle)

Comment: Да вышеуказанный пример выдаст ContentType и длину принятых данных, но не сами данные PostContent....переданные с использованием PostData. К сожалению выше указанный пример не чем не отличается от того что я привел в своем вопросе, выше. Интересует не сторонние решения, а именно как  в данном случае достучаться до данных Спасибо!